# Symfony Form Validate start and end dates

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I have symfony 4.10 and I am trying to ensure an endDate comes after a startDate. So I have this in my form:

```
$builder->add('endDate', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'M d, yy',
            ]);
            $builder->add('startDate', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'M d, yy H:i',
                'constraints' => [
                new GreaterThan([
                    'propertyPath' => 'parent.all[endDate].data'
                ]),
            ]
            ]);
```

But it does not seem to validate and the form thinks all is ok.

Is there a different way to compare the 2 values?

Form creation:

```
$event = new Event();
$form = $this->formFactory->create(FormType::class, $event);
$form->submit([
    'startDate' => 'Jul 22, 2020 16:00',
    'endDate' => 'Jul 7, 2020',
]);
if (!$form->isValid()) {
    ldd($this->formFactory->getErrors($form));
}
```

Comment: so the constraint currently validates that endDate < startDate, from your definition. maybe you mixed it up? also I believe just `'propertyPath' => 'endDate'`  should suffice according to https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/reference/constraints/GreaterThan.html#propertypath

Comment: I have tried to swap the date values to confirm and either way seems to run through sucessfully. One thing I suspect is because the format is a string. So is there a way to use the callback and get the value from another field in that callback?

Comment: I probably edited my comment too late ;o) and it should work with dates, since the docs mention "comparing dates". DateType will create Date objects, so it *should* work.

Comment: hmm unfortunately not, my form does not have any errors, even though these values have been submitted; `[startDate]: string(18) "Jul 22, 2020 16:00"
   [endDate]: string(18) "Jul 08, 2020 00:00"`

Comment: can you show more of the controller code?

Comment: I added the code to the end of the question. (Form creation:) (i hope thats what you meant?)

Comment: that's what I meant. Can't see any mistake so far ;o/ btw, there's also a DateTimeType, I doubt this being the cause though

Comment: Ok my fault :) I removed more code than I should have to show you. in the formFactor->create() i had option validation fields but non specified on my entities